# Which board's bootloader is on the microcontroller?

Tags: atmega2560

Currently I'm doing a project that needs an Atmega2560 standalone MCU. After I burned the bootloader with this method: http://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader . I set the Board as "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560" and the Processor as "ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)". But, it just stuck at "uploading" and this message pop up: "avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout". So, I'm guessing I'm choosing a wrong board. Is there a way to check which board to select in the Tool tab?

Comment: Do you have DTR connected via 0.1uF cap to create a Reset and start the bootloader code looking for a serial download?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on which bootloader you loaded, when you write your bootloader with AVRDude you specify the hex file, Which Hex file did you specify?

Comment: I burned through this method: http://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader and I haven't use any Hex File with this method.

Comment: Nick Gammon's sketch for loading a bootloader holds 10 different bootloaders. The actual bootloader that is burned depends on the detected signature of the board being programmed. If this went well the following bootloader should have been programmed "Atmega2560 with fixes for watchdog timer problem (8192 bytes)". With Nick Gammon's sketch you can also verify the existing bootloader. Dit you try that?